# Change background daily

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this may be easy , but I am not that good in JS . 
I have got 5 images and I want the body background to be one of them each day .

I have tried this :

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#daily {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
<script>
var backImg = ['http://example.com/path/image.gif', 'http://example.com/path/image1.gif', 'http://example.com/path/image2.gif', 'http://example.com/path/image3.gif' , 'http://example.com/path/image4.gif'];
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDate();
document.getElementById('daily').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+backImg[--day]+')';
</script>
<body>
<div id="daily">
<p>some text</p>
</div>
</body>
```

But , Unfortunately it doesn't work . 
Is there any other way to do this ? 
Please help , thanks

Comment: there are a lot of scripts to do this, just use Google. If you want to learn the code, you can check theirs so you learn how to apply to your own, or simply use one of the many free available scripts

Comment: `getDate` will get the day of the month, not the weekday. `getDay` is the method you want to use, it returns a value between 0 for Sunday to 6 for Saturday.

Comment: Why bother? Just set a cron on your server to change the symlink to a different image and make the background static html/css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only have five images and the date could be more than 5, you'll need to use the remaining value instead of the date. In your code, replace `backImg[--day]` with `backImg[day % backImg.length]`.

Also, you'll need to put your function in an onload event or on the bottom of the page. e.g.

```
window.onload = function(){ 
// your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a new image each day, you should use days since the epoch as base for your calculation. Then use modulo 5:

```
<script>
var backImg = ['http://example.com/path/image.gif', ..];
var today = new Date();
var day = Math.floor(today/8.64e7);
document.getElementById('daily').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+backImg[day%5]+')';
</script>
```

Edit: I'm dividing by 8.64e7 (8.64 * 10^7) which is the number of milliseconds per day.

Comment: -1 : You might want to explain the reason for using `8.64e7` in your script, I'm pretty sure it's not obivous for the OP.

Comment: @Alexis Pigeon What makes you say that? I clearly state that I'm calculating days since the Epoch. If you think it's unclear, you could just say so instead of downvoting.

Comment: Best practice would have been to write `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` instead of `8.64e7`, just saying.